# C# wpf изменение кнопки в зависимости от данных в объекте

Tags: c#, wpf

Добрый день!
Не могу понять, почему не работает кнопка, по выполнению условия.
Есть некий объект Client, который подключается к серверу.
У него есть свойство ifConnect.
Если сервер не доступен, то кнопка не делает никаких действий, и соответственно ifConnect = false.
Как только произошло подключение, то необходимо авторизоваться, но кнопка так же не производит никаких действий.

По сути даже необходимо иметь одну кнопку. Которая, при первом нажатии проводить подключение а при втором меняет метод на авторизацию.

```
if (client.ifConnect == false)
        ConnectBtn.Click += Connect_Click;
        if (client.ifConnect)
            AutorizatBtn.Click += Autorizat_Click;



    private void Autorizat_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       string userName = UserNameTxt.Text;

        if (client.Authorizat(userName))
        {
            NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
            nav.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
       else 
        {
            AutorizatTextBlock.Text = "Неверное имя или пароль";

        };
    }

    private void Connect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        client.Connect();
        if (client.ifConnect)
            AutorizatTextBlock.Text = "Успешное подключение";
        else AutorizatTextBlock.Text = "Сервер не доступен";
    }


public void Connect ()
        {
        try
        {
            if (!ifConnect)
            {
                client = new TcpClient(address, port);
                stream = client.GetStream();
                ifConnect = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ifConnect = false;
        }
    }
```

Если убрать условия, то кнопка работает.

Comment: Вы же не думаете, что если вы поменяете значение булевой переменной, автоматически произойдёт переподписка на события?

Comment: Вот этот момент то я и хочу понять. Каким образом производить смену событий.

Comment: upd/ а собственно понял, само понятие "события" я упустил в своем самообучении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xaml:

```
<Button Name="ConnectionButton" Loaded="ConnectionButton_Loaded" Click="ConnectionButton_Click">Connect</Button>
```

Codebehind:

```
private void ConnectionButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (ConnectionButton.Content)
    {
        case "Connect":
            client.Connect();
            if (client.Connected)
            {
                AutorizatTextBlock.Text = "Успешное подключение";
            }
            else AutorizatTextBlock.Text = "Сервер не доступен";
            break;
        case "Authorize":
            if (client.Authorize("UserName"))
            {
                AutorizatTextBlock.Text = "Authorized";
            }
            else
            {
                AutorizatTextBlock.Text = "Неверное имя или пароль";
            };
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception();
    }
}  

private void ConnectionButton_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    client.ConnectionChanged += ((connected) => { ConnectionButton.Content = connected ? "Authorize" : "Connect"; });
}

public class Client
{
    private bool connected;
    public bool Connected
    {
        get => connected;
        set
        {
            if (connected != value)
            {
                connected = value;
                ConnectionChanged(connected);
            }
        }
    }

    public delegate void ConnectionChangedHandler(bool connected);
    public event ConnectionChangedHandler ConnectionChanged;

    public void Connect()
    {
        Connected = true;
    }

    public bool Authorize(string User) => true;
}
```